# Calling Symfony2 app with invalid locale, first causes generation of MessageCatalogue, then Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime

Tags: php, symfony, twig, translation

I have a Symfony2 (2.6) application and now and then I get "critical errors" as the following one:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown
during the rendering of a template ("Circular reference detected when 
adding a fallback catalogue for locale "".") in 
"AcmeBundle:Content:home.html.twig" at line 2." at /home/acme/acme/app
/cache/prod/classes.php.cache line 5176
```

After doing some research/debugging I found out, that whenever someone calls the app with an invalid locale (=> http://acme.com/invalidLocale/ instead of http://acme.com/en/ => only "en" and "de" are allowed) Symfony creates a MessageCatalogue in the cache directory (app/cache/prod/translations). Then the app renders the page properly with the fallback locale (en).

Calling the app a second time with the same "invalid/undefined" locale causes the above mentioned error, renders an Error500 page and sends me the mentioned email.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

I would either expect a 404 error already on the first call, or a 301-redirect to the fallback locale "en", but not an 500 error.

Thanx for you help!

Cheers,
d.

Comment: The error message indicate that you have a cyclic dependency with your templates. So best start with showing how your `AcmeBundle:Content:home.html.twig` template and the templates it depends on looks like.

Comment: Could you also post your translation configuration settings from app/config.yml?  You can also [turn off that logging](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#reference-framework-translator-logging) in debug mode (which was introduced in Symfony 2.6)

Comment: Hi Jason,

here's the extract from my config.yml:
`code`
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
`code`

I don't want to turn off logging, I want to know if an error occurs in my app, but I want to avoid error500 when there should be a 404 or a redirect.

Cheers,
D.

Comment: Hi xabbuh,

the cyclic dependency issue is the result of the problem I want to fix. 

If the root-issue is not fixed, my cache will end up with tons and tons of "invalid" MessageCatalogues and the log will contain lots of 404-errors.

So why is Symfony creating MessageCatalogues for invalid locales? Can this be turned off?

Cheers,
D.

Comment: did you solve this? I have the same 500 error issue

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a solution yet (and I must admit I didn't look for one for the last 12 months). I still get the same errors (and invalid message-catalogues in my cache).